# Least cumbersome way to unambiguously reference an ambiguous column alias?

Tags: sql-server, alias

I’m fetching some data from a SQL Server database that I did not set up. It’s a production environment, so I don’t want to change more than I absolutely have to.

I’m fetching data and populating various types of objects with the data fetched. Some objects require data from just one table; others require joins to get all the necessary data.

There are a lot of tables which have a timestamp column `time`, usually stored in a `datetime` or `datetimeoffset` column type. This is usually the column queries should be ordered by. There are a couple of tables, though, where the timestamp is instead stored in an `ndate` column (storing only the date) and an `ntime` column (storing only the time). Adding the values together yields a proper timestamp.

The easiest and most obvious thing to do, then, to make this table behave like the others and have the columns map to object properties, is simply:

```
SELECT *, (ndate + ntime) AS time 
FROM tableA 
WHERE x = z 
ORDER BY time DESC
```

This works just fine. But if the object is one of the ones that require data from several tables, an obvious issue pops up. If `tableA` joins `tableB` and the latter has a `time` column, then I cannot figure out how to order the query by the aliased `time` column:

```
SELECT *, (ndate + ntime) AS time 
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB 
WHERE x = z 
ORDER BY time DESC
```

– yields a notice that `time` is ambiguous, which of course it is.

```
SELECT *, (ndate + ntime) AS time 
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB 
WHERE x = z 
ORDER BY tableA.time DESC
```

– yields a notice that `tableA.time` is an invalid column, which of course it is, since it’s not a column that actually exists in the table.

There are of course various more or less cumbersome ways of getting around this. The easiest way I’ve managed to come up with is to ‘wrap’ `tableA` (with the aliased column) in a subquery, which will then have a referenceable alias that makes the column unambiguous:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT *, (ndate + ntime) AS time 
     FROM tableA) AS subTable 
LEFT JOIN tableB 
WHERE x = z 
ORDER BY subTable.time DESC
```

This is what I would call fairly simple, but it still makes the query a lot less readable than the original, which is extremely simple.

Clearly, this is not what you’d call a serious problem, but it still made me wonder if there might not be a less ‘disruptive’ way of achieving the same end goal.

**Is there an even less intrusive way of doing this, which retains more of the simplicity of the original query?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "cross apply" or simply use the original expression for order by. ie:

```
SELECT *, (ndate + ntime) AS time 
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB 
WHERE x = z 
ORDER BY (ndate + ntime) DESC;
```

NOTE: Here there is a problem of trying to create multiple "time" columns in the result set using *. Probably you would instead list your wanted columns (which is the recommended way anyway). Or name your "time" to something else.

Comment: Very elegant and readable indeed. And so obvious now you’ve said it that I can’t believe it never occurred to me!

Answer (score 1):

Yes - `ORDER BY 1` will order by the first column of your select, whatever it is. Of course if you change the first column the order by changes

```
SELECT (tableA.ndate + tableA.ntime) AS time, tableA.*, tableB.*
FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB WHERE x = z ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Since you don't know how many columns are in `*`, you put the order by column first.

You might want to add a calculated column that creates `time` for you.

## EDIT

I'm not sure what the confusion about outer joins are in the comments below. I've added some detail to the query.

Comment: This is excellent—I had no idea `ORDER BY` accepts numeric parameters!

Comment: Its a lazy way of doing it though. I would always order by `(ndate + ntime)`

Comment: I certainly never use it in production code. But it does answer the question.

Comment: @TomC But it’s still very useful to know, hence my +1. As it happens, in my case it won’t work very well, but that’s incidental. Since `tableB` also has a `time` field and is `LEFT JOIN`’ed, `tableB.time` may sometimes be `NULL`. The order clause still works fine, but if the aliased `time` column is first, once the result set gets sent back to the PHP script where the query was called, `$row->time` will be empty. So in this _particular_ instance, I do need it to come last, but that’s outside the scope of what I actually asked.

Comment: I don't quite understand - are you saying in the ORDER BY that you need NULLs to come last (or first?)

Comment: @Nick No, I’m saying I need the aliased `time` column to come last in the list of columns fetched, so `*, (ndate + ntime) AS time` rather than `(ndate + ntime) AS time, *`. Otherwise, the `time` column that gets sent back to PHP is null if there is no corresponding row in `tableB`.

Comment: The position of the column in the select doesn't have anything to do with the side of an outer join that it comes from. Let me edit my answer

Comment: @Nick I may have explained myself poorly. I select rows through PDO and fetch them with `\PDO::FETCH_OBJ`. If in a row `tableB.time` is NULL, then `$row->time`, when accessed in PHP, will also be NULL if the aliased column comes first in the select. If it comes last, however, `$row->time` has the value of the aliased column. I suspect PDO just doesn’t handle results with identically named columns very gracefully. In the database itself, it makes no discernible difference, only in PHP. (For some reason, I’m not getting comment notifications on this—not sure why.)

Comment: hmm I don't know much about PHP but It do know that select `*` is almost always bad practice - you should always explicitly name your columns. Maybe that will hwlp